# Compactness of $Y$ implies compactness of $X$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Question is as follows :

Suppose $p:X\rightarrow Y$ is a closed continuous surjection such that $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for each $y\in Y$. Show that if $Y$ is compact then $X$ is compact.

Hint :

> If $U$ is an open set containing $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ there is a neighborhood $W$ of $y$ such that $p^{-1}(W)\subseteq U$.

Let $U$ be an open set in $X$ such that $p^{-1}(\{y\})\subset U$. We then have $y\in p(U)$. Suppose $y\notin p(U)$, because $p$ is surjective there exists $x'\in X\setminus U$ such that $y=p(x')$. So, $x'\in p^{-1}(\{y\})\subset U$ a contradiction. So, $y\in p(U)$.

$U$ is open implies $X\setminus U$ is closed which implies $p(X\setminus U)$ is closed which implies $Y\setminus p(U)$ is closed which means $p(U)$ is open.

So, we have an open set $p(U)$ such that $y\in p(U)$.. If i have to set $W=p(U)$ then i need to have $p^{-1}(p(U))\subseteq U$ which is not true always.. Help me to clear this..

Comment: This may be easier to prove with the formulation of compactness that uses the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property). Are you interested in such a proof?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Please see the edit

Comment: @AymanHourieh : Can you help me to understand the proof using finite intersection property...

Comment: I half-typed an answer but euouae posted one before me. What's wrong with that proof?

Comment: @AymanHourieh : I was confused about the assumption that collection is closed under finite intersections... Now i got it... If you have another way of saying this please post your answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Claim:** With $p$ as above we have:

$$ X \space compact \iff Y \space compact$$

**Proof:**

Since $p: X \to Y$ is a continuous surjection we obtain the "$\implies$" direction.

For the converse pick $U_{\alpha}$ an open cover of $X$. Since $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact and is covered by $\cup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$ there is a finite subcover covering $p^{-1}(\{y\})$. We get $p^{-1}(\{y\}) \subset U_{\alpha (y)}:=\cup_{1 \leq i \leq m}U_{\alpha_i}$.
Because $p$ is closed we know that $F_{\alpha (y)}:=p(X\setminus U_{\alpha (y)})$ is closed aswell. Therefore $W_{\alpha (y)}:=Y\setminus F_{\alpha (y)}$ is open and $$p^{-1}(W_{\alpha (y)})=p^{-1}(Y \setminus F_{\alpha (y)})=X \setminus p^{-1}(F_{\alpha (y)})=X\setminus p^{-1}(p(X \setminus U_{\alpha (y)})) \subset U_{\alpha (y)}$$

where in the last step we used $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$ because there might be more elements mapping into $A$ (I leave it to you to figure this out, maybe draw a picture rather than prove it rigorously).

This actually proves the hint.

Now observe that $$\cup_{y \in Y} W_{\alpha (y)}=\cup_{y \in Y}Y \setminus p(X\setminus U_{\alpha(y)})=Y\setminus \cap_{y \in Y}p(X \setminus U_{\alpha(y)}) \supset Y\setminus p(\cap_{y \in Y}X\setminus U_{\alpha(y)})=Y \setminus p(X\setminus \cup_{y\in Y}U_{\alpha(y)}) \supset Y$$

where in the last step we used the fact that $p^{-1}(\{y\})\subset U_{\alpha(y)}$. (To see the set-theoretic argument of the inclusion draw a picture).

Finally use the compactness of $Y$ to extract a finite subcover $\{W_{\alpha(y)_j}\}_{1\leq j \leq n}$ of $Y$. We then obtain:

$$X=\cup_{1 \le j \le n}p^{-1}(W_{\alpha(y)_j}) \subset \cup_{1 \le j \le n} U_{\alpha(y)_j}$$

Since the $U_{\alpha(y)}$ are just finite unions of sets in the open cover $U_{\alpha}$ we were able to finde a finite subcover of the original (arbitrary) cover. This gives us the compactness of $X$ and concludes the proof.

Comment: Sorry you edited the question while I was typing so my attempt doesn't  us the finite intersection property. I hope my approach is clear, let me know if there is something bothering you.

Comment: Your claim that there is a $y \in Y$ such that $p^{-1} (\{y\}) \in U_\alpha$ (I'm sure you mean "$\subseteq$" here) is false. Suppose that $X = [0,1] \times \{0,1\}$ and $Y = [0,1]$ with $p$ the obvious projection. If $U_\alpha = [0,1] \times \{0\}$, then there is no such $y \in Y$.

Comment: @euouae  Yes you are right, I noticed a few minutes ago and figured out I didn't use the compactness of $p^{-1}(\{y\})$. I think now it's correct.

Comment: The counterexample of euouae still stands. $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a set and there is no reason that it lies in one $U_\alpha$. The compactness of only implies that it lies in finitely many $U_\alpha$.

Comment: But after a minor correction your proof seems to be correct.

Comment: That's why I wrote w.l.o.g. You can simply take the finite union of these $U_{\alpha_j}$'s to be the 'new' $U_{\alpha}$

Comment: Then it would be a weird way to use wlog.

Comment: Ok, I'll change it:)

Comment: @noctusraid : I have edited the question only because some one has suggested that it may be easy to use finite intersection property... Any answer that does not use finite intersection property is very much welcome.. You said you will change it in last comment.. Please do that when ever possible.. I am ready to give +1 :D

Comment: @cello Oh my, I hope this time around it's okay. This set theoretic arguments always give me a headache, but it's important not to forget the idea of this exercise which is hidden behind all the formalism.

Comment: @cello everything ok now?:)

Comment: yes @noctusraid

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\{ U_i : i \in I \}$ is an open cover of $X$.

Consider the family $\mathcal V$ of all sets of the form $$Y \setminus p [ X \setminus ( U_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_n} ) ]$$ where $i_1, \ldots , i_n \in I$.  It is fairly straightforward to show that this is a family of open subsets of $Y$. Furthermore, given $y \in Y$ as $p^{-1} (y)$ is compact and $\{ U_i : i \in I \}$ covers this set, there are $i_1, \ldots , i_n \in I$ such that $p^{-1}(y) \subseteq U_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_n}$. It follows that $p^{-1}(y) \cap X \setminus ( U_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_n} ) = \emptyset$, and so $y \notin p[ X \setminus ( U_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_n} ) ]$, and so $y \in Y \setminus p[ X \setminus ( U_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_n} ) ]$. That is, $\mathcal V$ covers $Y$.

By compactness of $Y$ there are $V_i , \ldots , V_m \in \mathcal V$ such that $Y = V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_m$.  For each $j \leq m$ there are $i_{j,1} , \ldots , i_{j,n_j} \in I$ such that $$V_j = Y \setminus p [ X \setminus ( U_{i_{j,1}} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_{j,n_j}} ) ].$$ In particular, only finitely many $i$ appear as a $i_{j,k}$. If $\{ U_{i_{j,k}} : j \leq m, k \leq n_j \}$ does not cover $X$, take $x \in X$ not in the union.

Given $j \leq m$ it follows that $x \notin U_{i_{j,1}} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_{j,n_j}}$, and so $x \in X \setminus ( U_{i_{j,1}} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_{j,n_j}} )$, and so $p(x) \in p [ X \setminus ( U_{i_{j,1}} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_{j,n_j}} ) ]$, and so $p(x) \notin Y \setminus p [ X \setminus ( U_{i_{j,1}} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_{j,n_j}} ) ] = V_j$. This then contradicts that $V_1, \ldots , V_m$ covers $Y$!

Therefore it must be that $\{ U_{i_{j,k}} : j \leq m, k \leq n_j \}$ covers $X$.

---

To use the "family of closed subsets with the finite intersection property" characterisation of compactness, you will likely have to also consider finite subfamilies of this family. To wit:

Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of closed subsets of $X$ with the finite intersection property. Note that without loss of generality we may assume that $\mathcal F$ is closed under finite intersections (i.e., if $F_1 , \ldots , F_n \in \mathcal F$, then $F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n \in \mathcal F$).  (If needed, just replace $\mathcal F$ with the family $\{ F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n : F_1 , \ldots , F_n \in \mathcal F \}$. This is clearly also a family of closed subsets of $X$, and as any finite intersection of sets in this family is at heart an intersection of finitely many sets from the original $\mathcal F$, it also has the finite intersection property.)

Consider the family $\{ p[F] : F \in \mathcal F \}$. As $p$ is a closed mapping, this is a family of closed subsets of $Y$.  It also follows that this family has the finite intersection property. (Given $F_1 , \ldots , F_n \in \mathcal F$, if you pick $x \in F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n$ — remember that $\mathcal F$ has the finite intersection property — then $p(x) \in p[F_1] \cap \cdots \cap p[F_n]$.)  By compactness of $Y$ it follows that $\bigcap \{ p[F] : F \in \mathcal F \}$ is nonempty, so pick $y$ in the intersection.

By assumption $p^{-1} \{ y \}$ is a compact subset of $X$, and clearly $\{ p^{-1} \{ y \} \cap F : F \in \mathcal F \}$ is a family of closed subsets of $p^{-1} \{ y \}$. I claim that *this* family has the finite intersection property.

- Given $F_1 , \ldots , F_n \in \mathcal F$, note that $( p^{-1} \{ y \} \cap F_1 ) \cap \cdots \cap ( p^{-1} \{ y \} \cap F_n ) = p^{-1} \{ y \} \cap ( F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n )$. By assumption $F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n \in \mathcal F$, and $y \in p[ F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n ] \subseteq p[F_1] \cap \cdots \cap p[F_n]$. Thus there is an $x \in F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n$ such that $p(x) = y$, and so $p^{-1} \{ y \} \cap ( F_1 \cap \cdots \cap F_n ) \neq \emptyset$.

As $p^{-1} (y)$ is compact, it follows that $\bigcap \{ p^{-1} ( y ) \cap F : F \in \mathcal F \}$ is nonempty, so in particular $\bigcap \{ F : F \in \mathcal F \}$ is nonempty.

Comment: I would be more than happy to see other kind of solution.. See if you can help me to fill gaps in my solution..

Comment: @cello I have now included an f.i.p. argument. I have found it necessary to make the family of closed sets a bit more complicated, similarly to how my open cover of $Y$ was not a straightforward translation of the open cover of $X$.

Comment: One thing which i do not understand is why does $\{p(F)\}$ has finite intersection property

Comment: @cello I added a brief argument. Basically it is because $p[A \cap B] \subseteq p[A] \cap p[B]$, and so if you know that $A \cap B$ is nonempty, then $p[A] \cap p[B]$ must also be nonempty.

Comment: Here goes your +1.. I was using wrong definition of finite intersection property... I was saying that intersection is empty instead of non emprty.. That is why i got stuck...

Comment: Is it necessary to assume that  the collection is closed under finite intersections..  I mean to say it not that natural to guess.. So, it would be of some use if you can say something more about this way of approach...

Comment: I now understand your idea in assuming that collection is closed under finite intersections.. That makes a lot of sense.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal U$ be an ultrafilter on $X$. Then, $f\mathcal U$ is an ultrafilter on $Y$ and thus $f\mathcal U \to y$. Now, the claim is that for some $x$ in $f^{-1}(y)$, $\mathcal U \to x$. Otherwise, for all $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ we pick an open $V_x$ that is NOT in $\mathcal U$. Then, we use compactness to get a finite subcover $f^{-1}(y) \subset V_1 \cup \cdots \cup V_k$. But then, $X\setminus V_i \in \mathcal U$, and so $C = f(\bigcap X\setminus V_i) \in f\mathcal U$, is closed (since f is closed), and does not contain $y$, but that means $Y\setminus C$ is not in $f\mathcal U$, is open, and contains $y$. This contradiction shows that $\mathcal U \to x$ for some $x\in f^{-1}(y)$. Thus, $X$ is compact. This is actually just a repackaging of the above answers.

Comment: I am sorry but i do not know what an ultra filter is...

Comment: Here's some notes: https://math.berkeley.edu/~kruckman/ultrafilters.pdf it's pretty cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of closed sets in $X$ having finite intersection property.

Then $\{f(C)\}_{C\in \mathcal{C}}$ is a collection of closed sets in $Y$ as $f$ is closed.

See that $f\left(\bigcap _{i=1}^n\right)\subset \bigcap_{i=1}^n f(C_i)$. So, $\{f(C)\}_{C\in \mathcal{C}}$ has finite intersection
 property.

Because $Y$ is compact, this collection $\{f(C)\}_{C\in \mathcal{C}}$ has non empty intersection.

Let $y\in \bigcap f(C)$. The set $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact. The collection $\{f^{-1}(\{y\})\cap C : C\in \mathcal{C}\}$ is a collection of closed sets in 
 $f^{-1}(\{y\})$. As $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact, this collection has non empty intersection 
 if this has finite intersection property.

Enough to prove that $f^{-1}(\{y\})\bigcap (\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i)\neq \emptyset$. 
Otherwise, we have $f^{-1}(\{y\})\bigcap (\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i)= \emptyset$ 
i.e., $f^{-1}(\{y\})\subset (\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i)^c=\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i^c$.

---

So, $f^{-1}(y)\subset C_i^c$ for some 
$C_i\in \mathcal{C}$. So,$$y\in f(C_i^c)=f(X\setminus C_i)=f(X)\setminus f(C_i)=Y\setminus f(C_i)=f(C_i)^c$$
But then, we have assumed that $y\in f(C)$ for all $C\in\mathcal{C}$ and above conclusion says $y\notin f(C_i)$ for some $C_i$ a contradiction.
So,  $f^{-1}(\{y\})\bigcap (\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i)\neq \emptyset$ for any finite subcollection $\{C_i\}$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

---

The justification between above two lines is not correct as 
$f^{-1}(\{y\})\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i^c$ need not imply  $f^{-1}(y)\subset C_i^c$ for some $i$.

So, we change the collection... We can assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is such that $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under finite union.. This is same as considering the collection $\left\{f\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i\right)\right\}$.. So, from $f^{-1}(\{y\})\bigcap (\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i)= \emptyset$ we see that $f^{-1}(\{y\})\bigcap C=\emptyset$ for some $C=\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i$ in $\mathcal{C}$.... $f^{-1}(y)\subset C^c$ for some 
$C\in \mathcal{C}$. So,$$y\in f(C^c)=f(X\setminus C)=f(X)\setminus f(C)=Y\setminus f(C)=f(C)^c$$
But then, we have assumed that $y\in f(C)$ for all $C\in\mathcal{C}$ and above conclusion says $y\notin f(C)$ for some $C$ a contradiction.
So,  $f^{-1}(\{y\})\bigcap (\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i)\neq \emptyset$ for any finite subcollection $\{C_i\}$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

So, $\{f^{-1}(\{y\})\cap C : C\in \mathcal{C}\}$ collection of closed sets in compact set $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ has finite intersection proeprty.
So, $\bigcap (f^{-1}(\{y\})\bigcap C)\neq \emptyset$. So, $\bigcap C\neq \emptyset$ and so $X$ is compact.

Comment: Pretty close, but I think there are some problems here. For example, "...so $f^{-1}(y) \subset C_i^c$ for some $C_i\in \mathcal C$..." does not follow, as far as I can see.

Comment: @JustinYoung : Yes Yes... Can you help me to fill that gap...

Comment: Instead of $f(C)$ for $C\in \mathcal C$, try taking $f(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i)$ for $C_i \in \mathcal C$. This still has the FIP, but now if you have a point in the intersection you can argue it is in $f(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i)$. This will be a contradiction. Basically what I did was replace $\mathcal C$ by the filter generated by it.

Comment: @JustinYoung I believe your idea is useful in correcting that part but then i am not quite sure how to proceed... So, we are considering all collections $\{f\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i\right)\}$.. As this has finite intersection property, $y\in\bigcap f \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i\right)=\emptyset$.. So, we have $y\in f\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i\right)$.. Then what?

Comment: Repeat your argument, and you get that $f^{-1}(y) \cap (\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i )= \emptyset$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @JustinYoung : That i got it... But then i do not know where did i use that $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact... We have $y\in f\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i\right)$.. so, we have $f^{-1}(y)\subset \bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i$

Comment: Use your argument above, since $f^{-1}(y)$ intersects every finite intersection of $C$s non-trivially, the compactness tells you there is an element in $f^{-1}(y) \cap (\bigcap C)$, thus the intersection of the $C$s is nonempty. I'm just copying your proof!

Comment: @JustinYoung: I have edited the answer.. PLease see if it is fine now

Comment: Seems more or less fine, I would change the style some, but that's relatively  minor.